# Why would I get "Not a valid keystore file" error

Tags: android, keystore, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to set up an android build in Visual Studio App Center, but when trying to upload our keystore file I get the error "Not a valid keystore file". Could anyone think of a reason this could be happening? I have manually created a new keystore and that one seems to work. I can't use this though because its an existing app and would force users to uninstall and reinstall the app.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure the keystore file you are uploading has a file extension. MS appcenter doesn't like keystore files without an extension.

Name your file with a `.keystore` extension before uploading it and that should resolve the problem

Comment: i changed the .der extension to .keystore and it took the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file did not have a name; ie .keystore, changing this to MyApp.keystore resolved the problem